# Sqlite IN statement - getting list index instead of values

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite `IN` statement to obtain records from the `users` table like this:

```
select name from users where name in ("abc", "bcd", "def", "pqr", "xyz")
```

However, instead of retrieving the values that meet the condition, I'm interested in obtaining the indices (0-based) of these elements in a list. For instance, if the query yields the following values:

```
bcd
pqr
```

Instead, I'd like to generate a list of indices corresponding to these values like so:

```
1
3
```

Currently, I am using string comparisons for each result against the list. Since the list can contain 1000 or more items, this approach has become very slow. I like to know if there's a better solution that I might be overlooking.

Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The actual problem seems to be that the string comparisons against each result are slow. Can you post that code? There might be a faster way.